# How to parse XML Content without additional newlines and tabulators in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using the following xml file to read the contents of a file that I need to write to:

```
<properties>
    <url>http://www.leagueoflegends.com/service-status</url>
    <content>host=beta.lol.riotgames.com
xmpp_server_url=chat.na.lol.riotgames.com
lobbyLandingURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/pvpnet_landing
ladderURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/ladders
storyPageURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/story
lq_uri=https://lq.na.lol.riotgames.com/login-queue/rest/queue</content>
</properties>
```

I have intentionally made content element to have only the newlines and nothing else (instead of proper formatting).
However when I read the content element to a string it adds several newlines and tabulators on the beginning of the lines. The result I get by writing to a text file is the following text:

```
<imaginary newline here>
        host=beta.lol.riotgames.com
        xmpp_server_url=chat.na.lol.riotgames.com
        lobbyLandingURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/pvpnet_landing
        ladderURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/ladders
        storyPageURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/story
        lq_uri=https://lq.na.lol.riotgames.com/login-queue/rest/queue
<imaginary newline here><additional tab here>
```

The issue here is that I need that text to simply start from the first line, have no tabs, no spaces, just the newlines.

The C# code behind for reading the content tag is:

```
XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file), LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
PropertyFile PF = new PropertyFile();
PF.Content = (from Content in root.Descendants("content")
              select (string)Content.Value).Single();
```

file is the path to the file, as I am able to read everything else.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
PropertyFile class code ahead (content is just a string holding data for one file of a filetype I'm reading):

```
class PropertyFile
{
    public Uri URI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Desired output of the file is:

```
host=beta.lol.riotgames.com
xmpp_server_url=chat.na.lol.riotgames.com
lobbyLandingURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/pvpnet_landing
ladderURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/ladders
storyPageURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/story
lq_uri=https://lq.na.lol.riotgames.com/login-queue/rest/queue
```

Comment: What is `PropertyFile`? I suggest that this is the likley inserter of extra whitespace.

Comment: Umm nope, I figure it's making a confusion, so I'll add the class I've forgotten to already. It's just a data holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the LoadOptions to None:

```
XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file), LoadOptions.None);
```

According to MSDN, that will ignore all insignificant whitespace.

I tried it (with just a string for your XML - I didn't bother loading it from a file) and got the following:

host=beta.lol.riotgames.com
xmpp_server_url=chat.na.lol.riotgames.com
lobbyLandingURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/pvpnet_landing
ladderURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/ladders
storyPageURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/story
lq_uri=https://lq.na.lol.riotgames.com/login-queue/rest/queue

Is that what you're looking for?

**Edited To Add Code I Used**

```
string xml = @"<properties>
<url>http://www.leagueoflegends.com/service-status</url>
<content>host=beta.lol.riotgames.com
```

xmpp_server_url=chat.na.lol.riotgames.com
lobbyLandingURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/pvpnet_landing
ladderURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/ladders
storyPageURL=http://www.leagueoflegends.com/story
lq_uri=https://lq.na.lol.riotgames.com/login-queue/rest/queue
";

```
XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.None);
var content = (from Content in root.Descendants("content")
               select (string)Content.Value).Single();
```

Comment: Hmm...part of my code didn't format right, but I'm not sure how to get it to do so.  I copied and pasted what you put in your question into my test program.

Comment: There were two issues, first one was just what you said - I needed LoadOptions.None. And the other was... well that I messed up with some paths, so I was reading from an older xml that had those tabs and newlines. Still your answer held the important aspect of the solving, so I hope other's don't mind it. Other than that, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

By default the serialization of a XDocument/XElement formats (i.e. indents) the xml fragment.

Try using:

```
root.Save("Root.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

However any DOM operations won't be involved in insignificant spaces/tabs. What you write in an element, is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get if you try ...?

```
using System.IO;

XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file),
                              LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace); 
string content = (from Content in root.Descendants("content")
                   select (string)Content.Value).Single();
File.WriteAllText("SomeTempFile.txt", content);
```

I suspect that this text file will be formatted as you expect. This would indicate a problem with `PropertyFile`.

Comment: Interesting...I updated my test program to load from a file and then save to a file - I get the desired results with LoadOptions.PreserveWhiteSpace and LoadOptions.None.  Waaay past my bedtime...I'll be curious to see the answer tomorrow.